# Which of these devices is Ubuntu's CD-ROM?

Tags: mount, 14.10

```
ls /dev
block            mei                 sda2      tty3   tty6       ttyS30
bsg              mem                 sda5      tty30  tty60      ttyS31
bus              net                 sg0       tty31  tty61      ttyS4
char             network_latency     shm       tty32  tty62      ttyS5
console          network_throughput  snapshot  tty33  tty63      ttyS6
core             null                snd       tty34  tty7       ttyS7
cpu              port                stderr    tty35  tty8       ttyS8
cpu_dma_latency  ppp                 stdin     tty36  tty9       ttyS9
disk             psaux               stdout    tty37  ttyprintk  uinput
dri              ptmx                tty       tty38  ttyS0      urandom
ecryptfs         pts                 tty0      tty39  ttyS1      v4l
fb0              ram0                tty1      tty4   ttyS10     vcs
fb1              ram1                tty10     tty40  ttyS11     vcs1
fd               ram10               tty11     tty41  ttyS12     vcs2
full             ram11               tty12     tty42  ttyS13     vcs3
fuse             ram12               tty13     tty43  ttyS14     vcs4
hpet             ram13               tty14     tty44  ttyS15     vcs5
input            ram14               tty15     tty45  ttyS16     vcs6
kmsg             ram15               tty16     tty46  ttyS17     vcsa
kvm              ram2                tty17     tty47  ttyS18     vcsa1
log              ram3                tty18     tty48  ttyS19     vcsa2
loop0            ram4                tty19     tty49  ttyS2      vcsa3
loop1            ram5                tty2      tty5   ttyS20     vcsa4
loop2            ram6                tty20     tty50  ttyS21     vcsa5
loop3            ram7                tty21     tty51  ttyS22     vcsa6
loop4            ram8                tty22     tty52  ttyS23     vga_arbiter
loop5            ram9                tty23     tty53  ttyS24     video0
loop6            random              tty24     tty54  ttyS25     zero
loop7            rfkill              tty25     tty55  ttyS26
loop-control     rtc                 tty26     tty56  ttyS27
mapper           rtc0                tty27     tty57  ttyS28
mcelog           sda                 tty28     tty58  ttyS29
media0           sda1                tty29     tty59  ttyS3
```

Comment: None of these looks like it would definitely be a CD drive - closest is `/dev/sg0` which is a generic SCSI device but that's not definitely a CD.  That, along with the lack of a general `/dev/cdrom` indicates your system may have other issues recognising that drive.

Comment: kng190's suggestion for using `lsblk` command is a good one - try that and post output here for more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

None. You do not seem to have the usual ones, i.e., `cdrom`, `cdrw`, `dvdrom`, `dvdrw`, and `sr0`.

Comment: @Danatela are you sure? Cuz it perfectly answers the title. None of the listed devices is a cdrom ...

Comment: @Danatela I did not have enough points/rep to comment at the time

Answer (score 0):

```
$lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 452.6G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

"rom" is here.